# Rails admin: how to translate field names?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I'm using rails_admin ( https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin ) but i'm not able to translate  field names.

Here is a simplified version of my yml file:

```
pt-BR:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        password: "Senha"
```

Isn't this correct? I mean, shouldn't it translate "Password" to "Senha"?

Answer (score 0):

you should add your translation to `config/locales/rails_admin.pt-BR.yml` in fact you can start from this file:

https://gist.github.com/1844723#file_rails_admin.pt_br.yml

List of other languages is here: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Translations